# converting service file path on windows in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I am enumerating all the installed services on a windows machine (with OpenSCManager). The problem is that the returned exe paths are in different formats:

```
  C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
  \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\wd.sys
  system32\DRIVERS\wdcsam64.sys
  "C:\Windows\System32\wbengine.exe" 
  \??\C:\Windows\...
```

Is there a simple way to convert all this paths to absolute paths (C:\Folder1\Folder\fil1.ext), so i can open and read them (with CreateFile and ReadFile) without having to parse them?

Comment: I note that in that list, at least, only the device drivers are problematic.  You can get device driver information out of WMI, e.g., `wmic sysdriver list full` will show the driver paths in Win32 format.  The Setup API can presumably also retrieve this information.